# Change IntellIJ terminal to require "Shift" when copy/pasting

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, terminal-emulator

By default, IntelliJ has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> set as copy/paste shortcuts. This also applies to the terminal, though.

This is odd since (on Ubuntu at least) almost *every other* terminal uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for copy/paste shortcuts (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> sends `SIGINT`).

Changing the copy/paste shortcut in IntelliJ's settings changes the shortcut *everywhere*, but I don't want it to apply to the editor (just the terminal). This behavior is even mentioned in IntelliJ's terminal help page; https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html

> The embedded terminal emulator also inherits the following IDE settings:
>
> - On the Keymap page, you can configure the copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> shortcuts.

Is there some hidden setting I'm not seeing somewhere to change the copy/paste behavior of *just* the terminal in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known issue with no workarounds available at the moment:

- [IDEA-230084](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230084) In Idea's terminal on Linux, shortcuts Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Shift-C are swapped